# Loop in system call C program

Tags: c, loops

I want to call the function `wget` in a loop in ubuntu, how can I do it? This is what I did, but it didn't work.

```
for (i = 1; i < 500; ++i)
{
    system("wget -O page%i 'http://www.asdf.com/?=%i'", i, i);
}
```

Comment: Define _"it didn't work"_. What happened?

Comment: If you want call `wget` with parameters, so you should use [execl()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/execl)

Comment: you could sprintf() your command into a string and call system() with this string

Comment: If you want to spare yourself the trouble of running it from a C program, look at the `seq` and `xargs` commandline tools.

Comment: Perhaps a slight pause between each wget, just out of politeness?

Comment: @Mawg How can I do a 5 seconds pause?

Comment: A few hundred ms should do. Google for the sleep() function. E.g. http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Sleep_(system_call)#/C_examples     http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686298(v=vs.85).aspx   http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Sleeping.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use it like that.You need to use [`sprintf`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_sprintf.htm):

```
char cmd[50]={0};
for (i = 1; i < 500; ++i)
{
    sprintf(cmd,"wget -O page%i 'http://www.asdf.com/?=%i'",i,i);
    system(cmd);
}
```

Or you can use [`snprintf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/snprintf/) which will also prevent buffer overflow by limiting the size of the string to be copied. To use it,simply replace `sprintf` in the above code with

```
snprintf(cmd,sizeof(cmd),"wget -O page%i 'http://www.asdf.com/?=%i'",i,i);
```

Comment: prefer snprintf where you pass the size of the result buffer to avoid overflow

Comment: Edited the answer to include it.